# plot is not generated (gnuplot from command line)

Tags: linux, gnuplot

In sample.dat I have:

```
set terminal pngcairo  transparent enhanced font "arial,10" fontscale 1.0 size 500, 350 
set output 'simple.2.png'

plot [-pi/2:pi] cos(x),-(sin(x) > sin(x+1) ? sin(x) : sin(x+1))
```

From ubuntu/terminal I execute:

```
gnuplot -e "filename='sample.dat'"
```

but the `simple.2.png` file is not created. How do I export a plot to e.g png using gnuplot from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea where you got that from!

To execute a `gnuplot` script (here called `simple.gp`), simply call

```
gnuplot simple.gp
```

You should keep the extension `.dat` for data files.